# ASP grab two parameters from referral url

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Hi I am using a code to get the referral URL as you can see below:

```
sRef = encode(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

The code above is getting the following URL: 
http://www.rzammit.com/pages/linux-form.asp?adv=101&loc=349&websync=233344-4555665-454&ptu=454545

From that url I want to grab ONLY the ADV and LOC (Request.querystring doesnt work because this is a script which is run when the form is submitted)

So to cut the story short, by using the referral URL, i want to get out the values for the adv and loc parameters.

Any help please on how I can do this?

Below is the code I am currently using but I have a problem. The parameters which are after the loc, is showing as well. I want something dynamic. Also the values of the adv and loc can be longer.

```
    <%
sRef = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

a=instr(sRef, "adv")+4
b=instr(sRef, "&loc")

response.write(mid(sRef ,a,b-a))
response.write("<br>")
response.write(mid(sRef ,b+5))

%>
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question here: [ASP grab parameter from referral url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989169/asp-grab-parameter-from-referral-url)?

Comment: yes and it didnt work.. and this is my problem:  The parameters which are after the loc, is showing as well when i am returning the loc value. I want something dynamic which only grabs the adv and loc values.

Comment: Fiddle with the second `mid`. The other has a third parameter, you need that for the second one too.

Comment: You now have a few answers, did one of them work for you? Can you then please tag one as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started; it uses regular expressions to get all URL variables for you. You can use the split() function to split them on the "=" sign and get a simple array, or put them in a dictionary or whatever.

```
    Dim fieldcontent : fieldcontent = "http://www.rzammit.com/pages/linux-form.asp?adv=101&loc=349&websync=233344-4555665-454&ptu=454545"
    Dim regEx, Matches, Item
    Set regEx = New RegExp
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
        regEx.Global = True
        regEx.MultiLine = False

        regEx.Pattern = "(\?|&)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=([^&])"

        Set Matches  = regEx.Execute(fieldcontent)
        For Each Item in Matches
            response.write(Item.Value & "<br/>")
        Next

    Set regEx = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

substring everything after the ?.

Split on "&"

Iterate the array to find "adv=" and "loc="

Below is the code:

```
Dim fieldcontent 
fieldcontent = "http://www.rzammit.com/pages/linux-form.asp?adv=101&loc=349&websync=233344-4555665-454&ptu=454545"
fieldcontent = mid(fieldcontent,instr(fieldcontent,"?")+1)
Dim params
 params = Split(fieldcontent,"&")
for i = 0 to ubound(params) + 1
    if instr(params(i),"adv=")>0 then
        advvalue = mid(params(i),len("adv=")+1)
    end if
    if instr(params(i),"loc=")>0 then
       locvalue = mid(params(i),5)
    end if
next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following generic function:

```
function getQueryStringValueFromUrl(url, key)
    dim queryString, queryArray, i, value

    ' check if a querystring is present
    if not inStr(url, "?") > 0 then
        getQueryStringValueFromUrl = empty
    end if

    ' extract the querystring part from the url
    queryString = mid(url, inStr(url, "?") + 1)

    ' split the querystring into key/value pairs
    queryArray = split(queryString, "&")

    ' see if the key is present in the pairs
    for i = 0 to uBound(queryArray)
        if inStr(queryArray(i), key) = 1 then
            value = mid(queryArray(i), len(key) + 2)
        end if
    next

    ' return the value or empty if not found
    getQueryStringValueFromUrl = value
end function
```

In your case:

```
dim url
url = "http://www.rzammit.com/pages/linux-form.asp?adv=101&loc=349&websync=233344-4555665-454&ptu=454545"

response.write "ADV = " & getQueryStringValueFromUrl(url, "adv") & "<br />"
response.write "LOC = " & getQueryStringValueFromUrl(url, "loc")
```